# Does the flash fallback for mediaelement.js preload the audio file?

Tags: mediaelement.js

I have a general question about mediaelement.js when it loads the flash fallback in Internet Explorer v.6-8. If you do not have the preload="none" attribute in the  tag, does the flash player created by mediaelement preload the mp3?

I'm currently using mediaelement.js version 2.6.5.